# load function on react

Tags: reactjs, load

[image: I was trying to embed something from a different website but what happened is when I'm embedding the code on my react js app it send an error saying expect "}"]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        rec_embed_js.load({
            widget_id:"rec_job_listing_div",
            page_name:"Careers",
            source:"CareerSite",
            site:"https://bsa-solutions-inc.zohorecruit.com",
            empty_job_msg:"No current Openings"
        });
</script>
```

I was adding this on a jsx file but it sends me an error using curly brackets after the load function, I also tried changing the brackets to parenthesis but still it doesn't wo

Answer (score 0):

Change it to the following :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    __html: 'rec_embed_js.load({
              widget_id:"rec_job_listing_div",
              page_name:"Careers",
              source:"CareerSite",
              site:"https://examplesite",
              empty_job_msg:"No current Openings"
            });
            `,
</script>
```

Comment: Also tried adding it on react helmet and it's still not working.